# Find the list of polylines that fits a main polyline - Bus Routes and Bike paths

Tags: postgis

I have a list of Bus routes from GTFS. I also have a list of Bike Tracks as Polylines.
I'm looking to match the bus routes against the bike tracks. They dont match perfectly, so I just need the list of bike tracks sections that runs along a bus route section. I'm hoping to get as end result, for each bus route a list of bike tracks segments.

My initial thoughs to solve this problem is to split the bike track into multiple segments and start comparing points from bike track to points in my bus route.

Seems a bit naive this approach and I fear it won't have the best performance.

Is there a better way? To find the polyline that fits another polyline?

Thanks

Comment: Could you use st_buffer for a certain tolerance, then measure the intersecting areas?

Comment: That would work as well, but would not use existing indexes (which may or may not matter depending on the problem size).

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach would be to perform a [Spatial Join](https://postgis.net/workshops/postgis-intro/joins.html) using the [ST_DWithin](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html) function of PostGIS on the join condition.

You would pass your "tolerance" (how large can the closest distance between both polylines for you to still to consider them as "overlaps") as the distance in the third parameter. Note that this tolerance must be in the same SRID (coordinate system) of the input geometries (which must also be equal).

That is, if your coordinates are specified in degrees, and you want to have a tolerance of, say, 100 meters, you'd need to convert 100 meters to degrees too. Note that the physical size of a degree changes depending on your latitude (increasing as you move further away from the Equator), but this probably matters little to your scenario since you control the tolerance threshold (unless you're dealing with extreme latitudes for some reason).